# Key press event not working in fire fox for a textbox in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-selectors

I am pasting my sample code here i am trying to detect enter key on key press but it keep giving error in FF that e is undefined.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#txtDescript').keypress(function(e) {
        clearDescription(e)
    });
  });
```

My markup

```
 <input type="text" style="width: 350px; height: 50px;" id="txtDescript" value="Enter Description"class="TextBox"  onclick="clearDescription();"
                            onblur="blurDescription();" />
```

this is the function

```
function clearDescription(e) {
    debugger
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

    var keyPress = checkBrowser(e);
    if (keyPress == 13) {
        setDescription();
    }
}
```

Any solutions for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
onclick="clearDescription();"
```

you are not passing any argument to the `clearDescription` function which expects an `e` argument. Also because you are using jquery I don't really understand why you are mixing markup and javascript. Wouldn't it be better like this:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 350px; height: 50px;" id="txtDescript" value="Enter Description" class="TextBox" />
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#txtDescript').keypress(function(e) {
        clearDescription(e);
    }).click(function(e) {
        clearDescription(e);
    }).blur(function(e) {
        // As you haven't shown how the blurDescription
        // function look like you might want to check the arguments
        blurDescription(e);
    });
});
```

which could also be written like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#txtDescript')
        .keypress(clearDescription)
        .click(clearDescription)
        .blur(blurDescription);
});
```

All this being said, you could also take a look at the [jquery watermark plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) which provides similar functionality to what I suspect you are trying to implement.